# Handlebars not entering the condition even though the code seems right, doesn't give out errors

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with this handlebars code,
This is what it looks like:

```
{{#ifEquals "ciao" "ciao"}}
            <h1>########################</h1>
{{/ifEquals}}
```

And this is the helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEquals', function(a, b, options) {
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
        if (a === b) {
            return options.fn(this);
        } else {
            return options.inverse(this);
        }
      });
```

The problem I have is that handlebars doesn't show me the code inside the condition(`<h1>########################</h1>`) even if this is always true.
I've checked the values with the console.log while running the site and it returns the right ones.
Thanks in advance for any answer!

```
$(function(){   //doc ready
    let autorizzazione = getWithExpiry('autorizzazione');
    if(autorizzazione == null || autorizzazione == undefined)
    {
        window.location.replace("http://biolabitis.altervista.org/index.html");
    }
    Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
        return JSON.stringify(context);
    });

    Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEquals', function(a, b, options) {
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
        if (a === b) {
            console.log(options.fn(this));
            result = options.fn(this);
            return result();
        } else {
            console.log(options.inverse(this));
            return options.inverse(this);
        }
      });

    function getWithExpiry(key) {
        const itemStr = localStorage.getItem(key)
        // if the item doesn't exist, return null
        if (!itemStr) {
            return null
        }
        const item = JSON.parse(itemStr)
        const now = new Date()
        // compare the expiry time of the item with the current time
        if (now.getTime() > item.expiry) {
            // If the item is expired, delete the item from storage
            // and return null
            localStorage.removeItem(key)
            return null
        }
        return item.value
    }

    $('#logoutBTN').click(function()
    {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("utente");
        window.localStorage.removeItem("autorizzazione");
        document.location.replace("http://biolabitis.altervista.org/index.html");
    });

    $('#buttonSubmit').click(function()
    {
        let parolachiave = $("#parolaChiave").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: `http://biolabitis.altervista.org/API/Search_All.php?q=${parolachiave}`,
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data){
                    result = data;
                    console.log(result);
                    var template= $('#template-container').html();
                    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
                    $('#main').html(compiledTemplate(data)); 
                },
                error: function(){
                console.log("Errore");
                console.log(data);
                }

            });

    });

});
```

This is my html file (watch out i changed mainReagente to main in the javascript but still not working)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bio Lab ITIS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabelleStyle.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myRicerca.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.min-v4.5.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
        <ul class="ul-modified">
          <li class="nav-item li-modified">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Pagina Principale</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item li-modified">
            <a class="nav-link" href="attrezzatura.html">Attrezzatura</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item li li-modified">
            <a class="nav-link" href="strumentazione.html">Strumentazione</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item li li-modified">
            <a class="nav-link" href="reagenti.html">Reagenti</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item li li-modified">
            <a class="nav-link" href="esperienze.html">Esperienze</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item li li-modified">
            <a class="nav-link" href="pittogrammi.html">Pittogrammi</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item li li-modified">
            <a id="linkRicerca" class="nav-link" href="ricerca.html">Ricerca</a>
          </li>
          <li class="li li-modified">
            <a id="logoutBTN" class="button float-right">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>


    <div class="jumbotron text-center container-sm row pt-1 divcolor mb-1">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img src="immagini/logoBIOLABnoBCK.png" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Parola Chiave</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="parolaChiave">
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg float-right btn-color" id="buttonSubmit" data-dismiss="modal">Ricerca!</button>
      </div>
      <script id="template-container" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div id="template-container">
        {{#each result}}
        {{#ifEquals "ciao" "ciao"}}
            <h1>########################</h1>
        {{/ifEquals}}
        {{#ifEquals TABELLA "reagenti"}}
          <div id="main">
            <div class="container">


              <header class="text-center mb-5 text-white">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-7 mx-auto">
                    <h1>Lista dei Reagenti</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </header>


              <div class="card-columns">
                <!-- Produco una card per ogni record sul database-->

                <div class="card mb-5">

                  <div class="bg-white p-3 rounded-lg shadow">
                    <h1 class="h6 text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-2">{{this.NOME}}</h1>

                    <div class="custom-separator my-4 mx-auto bg-primary"></div>

                    <ul class="list-unstyled my-5 text-small text-left">

                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Formula: {{this.FORMULA}}</i>
                      </li>

                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Aspetto: {{this.ASPETTO}}</i>
                      </li>

                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Ditta: {{this.DITTA}}</i>
                      </li>

                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Scheda di Sicurezza: {{this.SCHEDA_SICUREZZA}}</i>
                      </li>

                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Quantità: {{this.QUANTITA}}</i>
                      </li>

                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Scadenza: {{this.SCADENZA}}</i>
                      </li>

                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Conservazione: {{this.CONSERVAZIONE}}</i>
                      </li>

                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Tipo di Conservazione: {{this.TIPO_CONSERVAZIONE}}</i>
                      </li>

                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Luogo di Conservazione: {{this.LUOGO_CONSERVAZIONE}}</i>
                      </li>


                      <li class="mb-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Codice Internazionale: {{this.CODICE_INTERNAZIONALE}}</i>
                      </li>

                    </ul>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Fine della produzione della card per ogni reagente -->

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {{else}}
          notfunctioning
          {{/ifEquals}}

          {{#ifEquals TABELLA "strumentazione"}}
          <div id="main">
                <div class="container">


                <header class="text-center mb-5 text-white">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7 mx-auto">
                      <h1>Lista della Strumentazione</h1>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </header>

                <div class="card-deck">
                  <!-- Produco una card per ogni record sul database-->

                  <div class="card mb-5">

                    <div class="bg-white p-3 rounded-lg shadow">
                      <h1 class="h6 text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-2">{{this.TIPO}}</h1>

                      <div class="custom-separator my-4 mx-auto bg-primary"></div>

                      <ul class="list-unstyled my-5 text-small text-left">

                        <li class="mb-1">
                          <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Caratteristiche: {{this.CARATTERISTICHE}}</i>
                        </li>


                        <li class="mb-1">
                          <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Tipo: {{this.ID}}</i>
                        </li>


                        <li class="mb-1">
                          <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Numero di Inventario: {{this.N_INVENTARIO}}</i>
                        </li>

                        <li class="mb-1">
                          <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Quantità: {{this.QUANTITA}}</i>
                        </li>


                        <li class="mb-1">
                          <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Collocazione: {{this.COLLOCAZIONE}}</i>
                        </li>


                        <li class="mb-1">
                          <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Collocazione del Manuale: {{this.COLLOCAZIONE_MANUALE}}</i>
                        </li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <!-- Fine della produzione della card per ogni Strumento -->

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {{else}}
            notfunctioning
            {{/ifEquals}}

            {{#ifEquals TABELLA "attrezzatura"}}
            <div id="main">
                <div class="container">


                    <header class="text-center mb-5 text-white">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-7 mx-auto">
                            <h1>Lista dell'Attrezzatura</h1>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </header>

                  <div class="card-deck">
                    <!-- Produco una card per ogni record sul database-->

                    <div class="card mb-5">

                      <div class="bg-white p-3 rounded-lg shadow">
                        <h1 class="h6 text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-2 text-center">{{this.TIPO}}</h1>

                        <div class="custom-separator my-4 mx-auto bg-primary"></div>

                        <ul class="list-unstyled my-5 text-small text-left">
                          <li class="mb-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Tipo: {{this.ID}}</i>
                          </li>
                          <li class="mb-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Quantità: {{this.QUANTITA}}</i>
                          </li>
                          <li class="mb-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Data Verifica Quantità: {{this.DATA_VERIFICA_QUANTITA}}</i>
                          </li>
                          <li class="mb-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-check mr-2">Collocazione: {{this.COLLOCAZIONE}}</i>
                          </li>

                        </ul>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Fine della produzione della card per ogni reagente -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {{else}}
          notfunctioning
          {{/ifEquals}}

          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Comment: @76484 Thanks for the response ```console.log( options.fn(this))``` gives out the code that should be rendered, but i can't figure out how to get out of this situation, any clue witht this hint

Comment: Does anything from your template get rendered? Is CSS hiding an element?

Comment: @76484 Nothing gets rendered in that page because of the different if, but in other pages where I have just plain handlebars without the ifEquals it renders out perfectly. I can show you the full code so maybe you can figure it out with me.

Comment: If the template function is executing - which it must be if the `console.log`s in its body are firing, then I think the problem is not with the Handlebars template function, but how you are adding its result to the DOM. Are you sure that `#mainReagente` exists in your document?

Comment: @76484 I've posted the orignial html file and i change it from mainReagente to main in all of the interested div. Still doesn't work. Can't find the issue (Thanks for you time hope i'm not annoying you!)

Comment: I don't know if it is the issue, but I wouldn't have the duplicate `#template-container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to attach your template output into an element that does not exist.

When you call `$('#main').html(compiledTemplate(data));`, you are asking jQuery to find the element with `id="main"` and to set its inner HTML to the result of calling `compiledTemplate(data)`. But jQuery cannot find any element with `id="main"` because none exists in your document.

To prove that jQuery cannot find a matching element, you could run the following: `console.log($('#main').length)`. If the result is 0, it is because jQuery found no elements matching the selector.

It is important to note that jQuery will not throw an Error when you call `.html()` (or any other method) on an empty result set. This is because even an empty result set is still a valid jQuery result Object.

You need to add the missing element to your document: `<div id="main"></div>`. But note: You do not want to duplicate this ID by including it in your template. The elements with `id="main"` in your template need different IDs.

Comment: OK solved the problem! @76484 Thank you so much! At the end i had to put a single ```<div id="main"></div>``` and i had to put it outside of the handlebars script in the html file.